# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' error when parsing a json in dart/flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, decode

I have a json with a test survey, it is written like so:

```
{
  "title": "Test Survey",
  "description": "This is a test survey, created for the sole purpose of testing the application",
  "questions": [
    "Question number 1?",
    "Question number 2?",
    "Question number 3?",
    "Question number 4?",
    "Question number 5?"
  ]
}
```

In order to retrieve and parse the json, I have this function:

```
  Future<void> _getData(String location) async {
    var json = await rootBundle.loadString(location);
    //print(json);
    Map<String, dynamic> parsed = jsonDecode(json);
    _survey = SurveyData.fromJson(parsed);
  }
```

Everything works fine until it comes to the line `Map<String, dynamic> parsed = jsonDecode(json);`, where everything stops due to the error `Field '_survey@34225648' has not been initialized`. Upon printing json (in the print line), I get the error `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I searched across all stackoverflow but no one had quite the same issue; maybe there's another way of parsing a json with mixed types.

[EDIT:] SurveyData class

```
class SurveyData {

  String title = "";
  String description = "";
  List<String> questions = [];

  SurveyData({required this.title, required this.description, required this.questions});

  SurveyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'],
        description = json['description'],
        questions = json['questions'];

}
```

full SurveyUtilities class, where the parsing happens

```
class SurveyUtilities {

  late SurveyData _survey;

  /// function that retrieves and parses survey data from database *
  Future<void> _getData(String location) async {
    var json = await rootBundle.loadString(location);
    print(json);
    Map<String, dynamic> parsed = jsonDecode(json);
    _survey = SurveyData.fromJson(parsed);
  }

  /// function that allows app to get parsed data to display in a page *
  SurveyData getParsedData(String location) {
    _getData(location);
    return _survey;
  }

}
```

snippet of code that requests for the json to be parsed, in order to create a new flutter page, where `sUtil` is the instance of SurveyUtilities and `survey` is a simple class holding two strings, the title and the location.

```
GestureDetector(
                child: const Text(
                  "partecipa al sondaggio",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SurveyPage(data: sUtil.getParsedData(survey.location)),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that the error appears while parsing the json string? I tested it on my machine and it works. https://dartpad.dev/?id=bbd3f10c2593f0add04dd770318b33f7

Comment: @TripleNine By debbuging it, everything goes fine until the program exits the "jsonDecode" function; the json gets printed just fine before decoding, so it got read after all.

Comment: @TripleNine I edited the post and added my SurveyData class. Something might be wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `List<String>` from questions mapping

```
class SurveyData {

  String title = "";
  String description = "";
  List<String> questions = [];

  SurveyData({required this.title, required this.description, required this.questions});

  SurveyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'],
        description = json['description'],
        questions = List<String>.from(json['questions']);

}
```

Comment: I get the same error, Field '_survey@34225648' has not been initialized, however the casting issue is no longer appearing. Something else appears to be blocking the parsing

Comment: Please share your full code of _getData function and respective class